# Pass function into useeffect and return result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return, use-effect, use-state

**Background:**

I have a `useEffect` that only runs once of the page render. I use it on a number of routes.

Its getting repetitive to type and was looking at putting it into a function_helper file I have that contains helpful reusable bits of code.

---

**Goal:**

I am trying to put this `useEffect` code into that helper file and call it when I need it. I have gotten as far as to be able to call it and pass a function to run. However I am unable to get the return result from the function that I passed to call in the use effect. I dont always need a return on the function that's called, but I currently do and it would be handy to be able to do this.

---

**What I currently use:** (Not in the helper file, this is what I use in the actual component being rendered)

```
 const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
     useEffect( event => {
        setCount(100);
           function a(event) {
            function_abc()
        }
          a(event)
    }, [count])
```

---

**Code I have so far to achieve goal**

```
export  function useffect_run_once(function_to_run) {
    var result
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
     useEffect( event => {
        setCount(100);
           function a(event) {
            result =   function_to_run()
            console.log("ttttttttttttttttttt: ",result)
        }
          a(event)
    }, [count])
   // return result
    // runs once on page load. Due to the '[]'
}
```

---

**What I've tried**

I have tried various things like putting a return on each layer of the useEffect, Setting a result var to return, making them async with awaits.

Comment: your useEffect code is wrong. what exactly do you want to happen. with your code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you understand how `useEffect` works. Your `useEffect` code doesn't work and it doesn't run only once it will run continously. one of the dependencies of it is `count` and you are also setting `count` inside the `useEffect` so it will continue to run infinitely. you are also passing an `event` parameter to it which doesn't make sense `useEffect` function param does not take an argument itself.

I also don't know what you mean by return result return what result. useEffect doesn't return a result. if you want to run a regular function just run it and get it's result you don't need `useEffect`. if you want to run that function and get its result once use `setState` with a function.

like such:

```js
function run_once() {
    console.log('This runs once')
    return 4    // return this value once   
}


const [once, setOnce] = useState(run_once());

return (
    <div>
        Value: {once}
    </div>
)
```

if you wanted to use `useEffect` you could make sure your dependencies is an empty array:

```js
function run_once() {
    console.log('This runs once')
    return 4    // return this value once   
}

const [once, setOnce] = useState(0);

useEffect( () => {
    console.log('Setting once')
    setOnce(run_once())
}, [])   // dependencies is empty meaning it doesn't rerun `useEffect` again
```